# I cant run a while loop in python due to a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop, python-idle

Can't solve a syntax error in this simple program. I don't see why after looking at many tutorials that it won't run.

```
def wtf_whileloop():
    return int(5)
x=wtf_whileloop()
while x=5:
    print ("not yet")
    wtf_whileloop()
```

the "error" is the part of

```
while x=5:
```

the IDLE has a popup error saying "Invalid Syntax"

I sound really stupid asking this question but if someone would smack some sense into me and tell me how to run a loop, that would be nice.

Comment: you need `==` not `=`

Answer (score 4):

In Python, the [`==` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) is used to test for equality between two objects:

```
while x==5:
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> 1 == 1
True
>>> 1 == 2
False
>>>
```

The [`=` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) is only used for assignment:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
>>>
```